# 2nd deg system related to similarity transformation of a 2-by-2 matrix with complex conj. eigenvalues into real jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way to check in general if a system like:

$$\begin{aligned}&ad = 1/2\\&bc = -1/2 \\&ca =-1/2\\&db=-1/2\end{aligned}$$ has a solution?

PS: I know this is not strictly a linear algebra problem but, for not knowing a better tag, I can say that it arose when I tried to find the explicit similarity transformation from a $2\times2$ diagonal matrix with complex conjugate eigenvalues that are not real into the jordan real canonical form. I checked my simple algebra several times, and I still could not find a mistake, but apparently, this system of equations doesn't have a solution (because rescaling $a =1$ does not work).

**Edit:** Here is how I tried to figure out what the transition matrix is. Suppose $$P=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$ is such a matrix. Up to rescaling by $\frac1{\det(P)}$, we should have the following equality.

$$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x+iy&0\\0&x-iy\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} x&-y\\y&x\end{pmatrix}$$

Working out the left hand side and setting $z=x+iy$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} az&b\bar z\\cz&d\bar z\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} daz-cb\bar z&ba(-z+\bar z)\\dc(z-\bar z)&-bcz+ad\bar z\end{pmatrix} $$

Okay, this time I got different equations, but they still don't work. From the off-diagonal entries of the last matrix we immediately get:$$\begin{aligned}&ba=-1/2\\&dc=1/2\end{aligned}$$ From the diagonal entries, I'd expect to see

$$\begin{aligned}&
da=1/2\\&
cb=1/2\\&
bc=-1/2 \quad\text{What??}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I'm not sure about the general case, but this particular system cannot have a solution in the reals. Multiplying all four equations together yields $(abcd)^2 = -\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Are you sure there is no signal typo?

Comment: @SergioParreiras I uploaded my work. This makes me remember why I computational exercises from high-school upset me so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are after is the real Jordan Canonical Form of the matrix. In that case you are working with the wrong equations. The mistake here is that you are mixing real and complex valued variables.

Note that the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}x & -y \\ y & x\end{pmatrix}$$
has eigenvalues $x\pm iy$. The decomposition you want
$$P\begin{pmatrix}x+iy & 0 \\ 0 & x-iy\end{pmatrix}P^{-1} = A$$
simply corresponds to diagonalizing $A$, which we know to be possible since the eigenvalues are distinct (assuming $y\neq 0$ of course). However, you cannot require $P$ to be a real matrix. Geometrically, the matrix $A$ corresponds to a rotation and a dilation. You wouldn't expect the rotation to provide real eigenvectors unless it is a multiple of $\pi$.

Diagonalizing the matrix is probably easier than solving for the system of equations, but it is generally possible. For example, the equations you are supposed to obtain for the off-diagonal are
$$ab = \frac{\det P}{2i}$$
$$cd = \frac{\det P}{2i}$$
Anyways, if we diagonalize $A$, then we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}i & -i \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x + iy & 0 \\ 0 & x-iy\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x & -y \\ y & x\end{pmatrix}$$
which is, I think, what you were after.

Comment: Many, many thanks, EuYu. Now I see how I was terribly sloppy with the equations I got from the diagonal entries.

Answer (score 1):

As EuYu already answered in the comments this particular system does not have a real solution.

However, polynomial systems in several variables can be solved sometimes using Groebner basis method. Groebner basis allows you to place the system in triangular similar as when you do Gaussian elimination in linear algebra, but often the triangular system has more equations than the original one but sometimes it has less!

I computed the Groebner basis for your system using Maple and got that it was $\left\{1\right\}$, which means that the system does not have a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ as well.

A wonderful reference is the book "Using Algebraic Geometry" by Cox et. al.

Comment: Dear Sergio, thank you for your answer. I had heard about Groebner basis before, but I never knew that therein lies their usefulness.